# Books for studying non-linear dynamics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, research-level, non-linear-systems

I've recently developed interest into non-linear dynamics and chaos theory after having read a large part of the book by [Steven Strogatz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0813349109). Is it possible for me to delve into a research area dealing heavily with non-linear dynamics having read the book carefully and gone through its exercises? I understand that I'd need to be familiar with other topics relevant to the corresponding research area. But as far as my understanding of non-linear dynamics is concerned, would this book suffice? If not, what are some other books with a more advanced treatment of this subject?

Comment: Theory of Oscillators by Andronov, Dover Books.

Comment: This question would be better suited for this site if you removed the part about using Strogatz's book and ask only what books would be suited for studying NLD.